# Haskell: Pretty print infix and prefix

Tags: haskell, types, abstract-syntax-tree, pretty-print

I have a type to represent haskell types:

```
data Type 
    = TApp Type Type
    | TVar Name
    | TLit Name
infixl 8 `TApp`

-- a -> b
aToB = TLit "Fun" `TApp` TVar "a" `TApp` TVar "b"

-- Maybe (IO Int)
maybeIOInt = TLit "Maybe" `TApp` (TLit "IO" `TApp` TLit "Int")
```

I want to print it as haskell does, namely, literals that are symbols are printed infix while other literal are printed prefix.
also parenthesis should be added when necessary:

```
show aToB = "a -> b"
show maybeIOInt = "Maybe (IO Int)"

show ast = ???
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: If you are just doing this for your own edification I understand, otherwise I would point you to the [haskell-src-exts](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.19.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Pretty.html) which has both a pretty printer and an exact printer for Haskell code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to do this is thread through a precedence variable to your printing function. Also, you almost always should prefer a pretty printing library instead of just using raw strings (both for performance reasons, and ease). GHC ships with [`pretty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty) and I also recommend the newer [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter).

Using the former (and assuming `type Name = String`):

```
import Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ

prettyType :: Type -> Doc
prettyType = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> Type -> Doc
    go _ (TVar x) = text x
    go _ (TLit n) = text n
    go n (TLit "Fun" `TApp` l `TApp` r) = maybeParens (n > 0) (go 1 l <+> text "->" <+> go 0 r)
    go n (l `TApp` r) = maybeParens (n > 1) (go 1 l <+> go 2 r)
```